# jQuery continuously scales a div element using hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I recently tried to use jQuery's `effect('scale')` function with the `hover()` function in jQuery. The idea is to enlarge the div element on mouseenter, and shrink it back to normal on mouseleave. The code is as follows:

```
$('.boxgrid').hover(function(){
    $(this).effect('scale', {percent:125}, 1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).effect('scale', {percent:80}, 1000);
});
```

I tried testing this in a jsfiddle, but instead of upscaling and downscaling once when a mouse enters the element, it keeps enlarging it. You can see the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9GLEy/8/). My question is how do I fix it? My understanding was that the mouseenter event was fired only once, and reset when the mouseleaves event is fired, but this seems to say otherwise? Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It has the bizarre behavior in Firefox 3.6.15, but I just tried it in Chrome, and it seems to behave properly. So let me then ask if there is a better, more cross-browser way to do this?

Comment: It works in chrome, but not IE.

Comment: Tried in Chrome 10 and if you move in and out a few times it starts going sporadic like you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calls the hover function every time the animation finishes. I modified it as follows and it appears to work:

```
window.boxScaled = false;
$('.boxgrid').hover(function(){
    if(!window.boxScaled) {
        window.boxScaled = true;
        $(this).effect('scale', {percent:125}, 1000);
    }
}, function() {
    if(window.boxScaled) {
        window.boxScaled = false;   
    $(this).effect('scale', {percent:80}, 1000)
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ewan! I was thinking of using a flag with the function, even though it seems a bit workaroundish. I'm actually inclined to go with the solution @Adam Ayres suggested in his comments, since that seems like the more proper way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to force the animation to stop if you leave the box before it has finished scaling (or reenter the box before it has shrunk):

```
$('.boxgrid').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().effect('scale', {percent:125}, 1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().effect('scale', {percent:80}, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/9GLEy/10/

Your understanding of hover (mouseenter/mouseleave) is correct, they should only fire once upon entering/leaving.

Comment: I tested this and am able to get the box to shrink out of existence :o

Comment: Ah you are right, maybe using scaling for the shrinking is not what we want.  Maybe using "size" to go back to the original size is better: http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/9GLEy/15/

Comment: That example seems to allow you to still keep growing the box, how about using "size" for both directions: http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/9GLEy/16/

Comment: you're a genius! Thanks for the 'size' suggestion!

Comment: I happily take reward/payment in the form of the accepted answer :)